# How access and execute commands in Windows machine (Public IP) from Linux terminal (Public IP)

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, terminal

I have following machines available in my center and both has public access

```
192.100.0.1 (This runs in Ubuntu 18)    
192.100.0.2 (This runs in Windows server 2016)
```

And I am trying to do following actions from **Ubuntu machine to Windows machine** using terminal

1. Copy file from /var/lib/proceed/sample.jar to C:Users/usertest/Documents **// This is done Edited question**
2. Then, I want to access windows terminal from my Ubuntu terminal and execute windows command, as below

   ```
    cd C:\Users\plenty\test
    java -jar sample.jar
   ```

**Edit :** I have done with copy the file as follows,

```
sshpass -p 'password' scp /var/lib/proceed/sample.jar usertest@192.100.0.2:C:/Users/usertest/Documents
```

Installed **OpenSSH** in windows server to communicate from Ubuntu.

How to execute windows commands from Ubuntu terminal?

Comment: Any update from anyone in this please?

Comment: Hmm, it looks like you already have a ssh server installed on the Windows machine. Depending on what it is, you can probably use it to pass individual command or even to access a console Windows. You should at least say what ssh server is installed on the Windows machine. But I wonder whether this question would not be more on topic on SuperUser...

Comment: Yes, I forgotten. sorry to add that. Please take a look my edit. thanks

Comment: Have you tried to simply use `ssh` to connect from Ubuntu to Windows: `ssh usertest@192.100.0.2`?

Comment: Yes, it requires password. I am doing deployment in CICD from shell script. So I dont want to password

Comment: What about `sshpass -p 'password' ssh usertest@192.100.0.2 command` where command could be empty to get an interactive *shell* or a command to directly execute?